# How to edit variables while a cell is running in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

Apologies for this absolute noob question, previously when using Jupyter Notebook I have been able to change the values of variables in a currently running cell simply by defining them in another cell and running that one. For some reason this no longer works. I would like to regain this function so that I can change physical parameters inside a numerical integration loop while it is still running.

### First cell with loop

```
import time
t = 0

while t<20:
    t = t + 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t)
```

---

### Second cell

```
t = 1
```

---

If the first cell is running and I attempt to run the second one, Jupyter waits for the first to finish before executing the second. I would like to manually change variables while the loop is still running.

Comment: I don't think that can be done. Would be a bit odd too, as you wouldn't know where you are in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I thought that code execution had always been sequential in IPython kernels. There's typically only one thread to receive execution requests and to process them. See this discussion here from 2016, for example:
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1155

If you're certain that this has been working in the past, try to downgrade the `notebook` and `ipykernel` packages to the versions you used then.

There are enhancements to change the default behavior. For example a cell magic `%%async_run` described here:
https://github.com/leriomaggio/async-ipython-magic

You can use async/await with recent versions of IPython and IPyKernel in notebooks, but that requires changes to your code:
https://blog.jupyter.org/ipython-7-0-async-repl-a35ce050f7f7?gi=de4b6eb312a
https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html

There's also IPyParallel, but that seems to require more setup than a plain notebook:
https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll try these solutions. I too was surprised that this worked in the past and actually don't understand why it did.

Comment: it never has...